# Chart formatting getting in the way of my VBA range

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I am trying to pull data in a series of different instances. I am stuck on the first set of data I am pulling because I believe the way the chart is formatted is interferring with the location of my data. The data will affect the chart. The chart is located at Range A1:A23 through E1:E23. The data starts on B25:B36 through E25:E36. The data is pulling to V1.

```
Sub OneClickAuotFill()
    Dim Row2 As Long
    Dim Row3 As Long
    Dim Row4 As Long
    Dim Row5 As Long

    Row2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Row3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Row4 = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Row5 = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, works As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant

    Set ws = Sheets("Re-Releases")
    ws.Activate

    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\Users\sncook\Desktop\Engineering Charts\On Time Delivery Calc.xlsm"

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set works = ActiveSheet

    Dim PageName As Variant
    PageName = InputBox("Please Enter Page Name", "Information")
    ActiveSheet.Name = PageName

    'wb2.Worksheets("Re-Releases").Range("A24").Select
    wb2.Worksheets("Re-Releases").Cells(Row2 & 1).Value = wb.Worksheets(PageName).Range("M324").Value
    wb2.Worksheets("Re-Releases").Range("C" & Row3).Value = wb.Worksheets(PageName).Range("N324").Value
    wb2.Worksheets("Re-Releases").Range("D" & Row2).Formula = "=IFERROR(SUM(1-C:C/B:B), 0)"
    wb2.Worksheets("Re-Releases").Range("E" & Row2).Value = wb.Worksheets(PageName).Range("M324").Value

    wb.Close

    If wb2.Worksheets("Re-Releases").Range("B28") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Didn't Work"
    Else
        MsgBox "Did Work"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First thing I spot is the line `wb2.Worksheets("Re-Releases").Cells(Row2 & 1).Value` - what does `Cells(Row2 & 1)` mean? If `Row2` is a Long/Integer e.g. `4` then that will mean `Cells(41)` which doesn't make sense... it needs a column reference too

Comment: I know, but if I throw a column reference like B24 then it throws a mismatch error.

Comment: Are you trying like `.Range("A" & Row2).Value` just like the other lines below it?!

Comment: Yes I am, oh I guess it doesn't throw and error it just doesn't move any data over if I do it like that.